# errors with content discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def say(ctx, *, response):
  if "@" in say.content.contains:
    await ctx.send("no")
  else:
    response = response.replace("(", "")
    response = response.replace(")", "")
    await ctx.send(response)
```

I'm trying to make it so if you type .say then anything with an @ will cancel the command

error message:  if "@" in say.content.contains:
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'content'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'content'

Comment: Instead of `say.content` did you mean `ctx.message.content`? `say` is the name of your function, not a variable containing the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `say.content`. The variable `say` isn't the message being typed, it's the function/name of the function.

Try using `ctx.message.content` instead of `say.content`